# Create PaymentIntent and retrieve it

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm experimenting Stripe API to confirm a PaymentIntent.
Here is the flow from what I understand from the documentation.

1. The client app requests a paymentIntent from the backend
2. Backend creates the paymentIntent using secret key and returns the **client_secret**.
   (Stripe documentation https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create)[https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create]

   curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents 
   -u sk_test_xxx 
   -d amount=2000 
   -d currency=eur 
   -d "payment_method_types[]"=card

Returns the following payment intent object:

```
{
  "id": "pi_1HxXXXX",
  "object": "payment_intent",
  "amount": 2000,
  ...
  "client_secret": "pi_1HxXXXXX_secret_IVtXXXXX",
}
```

3. The client app retrieves the PaymentIntent from Stripe using the **public key** to confirm it.
   [Stripe documentation https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/retrieve](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/retrieve)

> When retrieved with a **publishable key**, only a subset of properties will be returned. Please refer to the payment intent object reference for more details.

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents/pi_1HxXXX?client_secret=pi_1HxXXX_secret_IVtpXXX' --header 'Authorization: Bearer pk_test_XXX'
```

Note that from the doc **client_secret** is required when using publishable key.

The curl command returns the following error:

```
{ "error": {
    "code": "resource_missing",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing",
    "message": "No such payment_intent: 'pi_1HxXXX'",
    "param": "intent",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

It means that the payment intent is not found but I can see it in the Stripe Event console [image].

Note: If I try to retrieve the PaymentIntent with the **secret key**, it's working:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents/pi_1HxXXX' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer sk_test_XXX'
```

So, my question is,

**how can we retrieve the payment intent using the Stripe's publishable key?**

Comment: Is there any chance something was typed wrong? I just tried the exact same curl command with the publishable key and it works fine for me

Comment: Are you using your Production Key in one case, and your Development Key in the other case by chance?

Comment: Which id do you use to retrieve the payment intent pi_xxx or pi_xxx_secret_xxx ?

Comment: I mess up with the publishable key. I don't know why I was able to use a wrong key. Using the correct Publishable Key works ! Thanks

Comment: :) Glad to help, that's got me a couple of times.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was not using the right key.
Using the right key makes it work.